# Uneven spaces between Isotope StraightDown Layout mode with Infinite Scroll

Tags: jquery, yii, jquery-isotope

I have a product listing with Infinite Scroll in Yii MVC. I have implemented two layout modes to increase user experience

```
$(".layouts .list").click(function () {
 jQuery(function() {
            var jQuerycontainer = jQuery('.items');
            jQuerycontainer.find('.view ').each(function() {
                jQuery(this).addClass('large');
            });
            jQuerycontainer.isotope({
                layoutMode: 'straightDown',
                itemSelector: '.view',
                straightDown: {
                      columnWidth: 50
                } 
            });
            $(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
                jQuery(".layouts .list").click();
            });
            jQuerycontainer.find('.view').removeClass('small');
            jQuery(this).addClass('large');});
   return false; });


//-----------------Grid Click Function---------------//   
    $(".layouts .grid").click(function () {
        jQuery(function() {
            var jQuerycontainer = jQuery('.items');
            jQuerycontainer.find('.view ').each(function() {
                jQuery(this).addClass('small');
            });
            jQuerycontainer.isotope({ 
                layoutMode: 'masonry',
                itemSelector: '.view',

                masonry: {
                    columnWidth: 50
                }
            });
            $(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
               jQuery(".layouts .grid").click();
            });
            jQuerycontainer.find('.view').removeClass('large');
            jQuery(this).addClass('small');
            jQuerycontainer.isotope('reLayout');

        }); 
 return false;   });
  });`
```

The main problem is that when i switch to grid it display the items in grid style.but when i switch back to List mode,It display the list correctly but with some uneven spaces after some of the items,when i re-click on list it automatically rearranged accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try something like this :

```
$container.isotope({
    masonry {
    columnWidth: 50,
    },
    straightDown: {
    columnWidth: 50,
    }
});


var isMasonry = true;

$('.layouts .grid').click( function() {

    isMasonry= !isMasonry;
    var sizeStyle = isMasonry ?
      { minWidth: '100%', minHeight: '100%' } :
      { minWidth: '100%', height: '100%' };

    $container.addClass('no-transition').css( sizeStyle );
    var redraw = $container[0].offsetHeight;

    $container.removeClass('no-transition')
    .isotope({
        layoutMode: isMasonry ? 'masonry' : 'straightDown'
    });
```

To avoid any gaps between isotope elements you need to do some tricks with css transition.

See an example made by David Desandro here : http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/ivjAI

Comment: Your example of David Desandro helps a lot.Thanks My problem was solved.